# Javascript: Terminate the program when CANCEL clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Scenario:**

I have a `confirmation pop up message` where when I click the `OK` button it will just proceed or will save the entry that I created - this is okay.. BUT when I click the `CANCEL` button it will go back to the page of `booking_content.php` - this one is okay...

**PROBLEM:**

the problem now is with the `CANCEL`, returning back to the page is good but `its still saving the entry which is when I pressed the`CANCEL`it will not save and will return back to the page of`booking_content.PHP`.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to `*terminate the program*` when I click the `CANCEL`? I also tried the `EXIT;` but its not working....

Here's my code of Javascript along with PHP:

```
// other if else..

else if($network == "Mass and Mobile" && $row[fldTotalDuration]  == "08:00:00"  && $duration >= "0 s")
{?><?php
if(sizeof($bldg) == 1)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "alert('$bldg[$i] station is already full.');\n";
echo "window.location='booking_content.php'";
echo "</script>";
}

else
{ ?>
<script>
var r=confirm('$bldg[$i] station is already full. Do you want to save the other networks?')
if (r==true) {
alert("OKAY BUTTON");
} else {
window.location='booking_content.php';

}
</script>
<?php
}

}

//after all the if else...

else
{
  // heres my code for saving the data....

}
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "terminate the program"? Kill the web server?

Comment: @slebetman....no..sorry...as for now, when I pressed the CANCEL it will just continue the saving....I want is....when I click the CANCEL it will proceed to the booking_content.php then it will not save also the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realize that PHP executes on the server to generate a large string which is then sent to the browser as an HTML file that contains the javascript don't you?

So, the code executes as follows:

1. The user makes request to 'booking_content.php'.
2. The web server executes PHP to process the 'booking_content.php' script.
3. The 'booking_content.php' script is executed including the `else` section that contains the code for saving the data.
4. Data is saved and HTML string is generated and sent to the user.
5. Browser receives the HTML and executes the javascript which prompts the user with the confirmation dialog.

Do you see the problem here? The data is saved long before the confirmation dialog is shown to the user.

The way around this is to pop the confirmation dialog before the user makes a request to 'booking_content.php'. It's usually done as an `onsubmit` event on the form that submits the data or manually calling the dialog function if the data is submitted via ajax.

Alternatively in cases where you need to check some data or status in the server before popping the dialog you can have a separate intermediate page to ask the confirmation. For example, create a 'booking_confirmation.php' that gets the data from the form which in turn asks the confirmation and then redirects to 'booking_content.php' when the user clicks OK (remembering to include the post data or query param).

Comment: @slebetman....sorry for late reply...I just read what you said and I tried to trace my code, and the result is your correct...thank you for helping me..probably, I just need to revised my code...